# ArrayList for String sorting

Tags: java, arraylist

ArrayList for String sorting :

```
public class Ooops<P, O> 
{
   private P po;
   private O pa;
   private int val;
   public Preference(P p, O o, int v) 
   {
        setPo(p);
        setPa(o);
        setValue(v);
   }
   //Getter and setter for Pa,Pa and val
}
```

I have created an Object of this class

```
   List<Ooops<String, String>> abc = new ArrayList<Oops<String, String>>();
```

Something like ,

```
 Xcf,PQR,8
 DBC,Pas,6
 LdC,PhR,3
```

Becomes

```
 DBC,Pas,6
 LdC,PhR,3
 Xcf,PQR,8
```

I am confused , how can I sort the object based on the value of variable po in the object.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Didn't you asked similar type of question few minutes back?

Comment: @Smit exactly the same. And a similar one a hour ago. Both with accepted answers.

Comment: Thanks !!! It helped me a lot !!! Well for string it is not , because it is not working because I have override the method, Therefore , I had asked it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the list using the Collections.sort method with a custom Comparator, adding the interface Comparable to Oooops will make life easier as well.

```
public class Ooops<P, O> implements Comparable<Ooops<P,O>> {

  private P po;
  private O pa;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Ooops<P, O> o) {
    return (po.toString()+pa.toString()).compareTo(o.po.toString()+o.pa.toString());   //Some common way to compare the two.
  }
}
```

Collections.sort can then be used to sort the list. Forcing P and O to extend Comparable would make the compateTo method somewhat more manageable.

ie;

```
public class Ooops<P extends Comparable<P>, O extends Comparable<O>> implements Comparable<Ooops<P,O>> {

  private P po;
  private O pa;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Ooops<P, O> o) {
    if (po.compareTo(o.po) == 0)
      return pa.compareTo(o.pa);
    else
      return po.compareTo(o.po);
  }
}
```

Alternative to changing Ooops is to create a custom comparator;

```
ArrayList<Ooops<String, String>> abc = new ArrayList<Ooops<String, String>>();
Collections.sort(abc, new Comparator<Ooops<String, String>> (){

  @Override
  public int compare(Ooops<String, String> o1, Ooops<String, String> o2) {
    return 0; //Compare the two.
  }

});
```